# Upgrading node version individually for each project

Tags: node.js, npm

I have two projects on-going, in one I need node v8 (yes, I know, it's very behind), and one in node v14. right now, across my local machine, globally, I have node v8 installed, but if I want to update my one project to node v14, and keep one at v8, is this possible? Can I just run `npm update` on my one project and it will keep v8 on my other, or will it do it globally?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We successfully use [nodenv](https://github.com/nodenv/nodenv) for managing node versions between projects. It allows many versions to be available simultaneously. Once set up you add a `.node-version` file to the root of your project and this will be the version accessed by nodenv.

There is also `nvm` node version manager, which many use, though I don't have much experience with it.